# Predict test data using model based on training data set?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-analysis, data-science

Im new to Data Science and Analysis. 
After going through a lot of kernels on Kaggle, I made a model that predicts the price of a property. Ive tested this model using my training data, but now I want to run it on my test data. Ive got a test.csv file and I want to use it. How do I do that?
What i previously did with my training dataset:

```
#loading my train dataset into python
train = pd.read_csv('/Users/sohaib/Downloads/test.csv')

#factors that will predict the price
train_pr = ['OverallQual','GrLivArea','GarageCars','TotalBsmtSF','FullBath','YearBuilt']

#set my model to DecisionTree
model = DecisionTreeRegressor()

#set prediction data to factors that will predict, and set target to SalePrice
prdata = train[train_pr]
target = train.SalePrice

#fitting model with prediction data and telling it my target
model.fit(prdata, target)

model.predict(prdata.head())
```

Now what I tried to do is, copy the whole code, and change the "train" with "test", and "predate" with "testprdata", and I thought it will work, but sadly no. I know I'm doing something wrong with this, idk what it is.

Comment: Please add the code that you tried fir the test data, including the full error that you got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you process the train and test data exactly the same way, that `predict` function will work on either data set.  So you'll want to load both the train and test sets, `fit` on the train, and `predict` on either just the test or both the train and test.

Also, note the file you're reading is the `test` data.  Assuming your file is named properly, even though you named the variable to be `train`, you are currently training on your test data.

```
#loading my train dataset into python
train = pd.read_csv('/Users/sohaib/Downloads/train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('/Users/sohaib/Downloads/test.csv')

#factors that will predict the price
desired_factors = ['OverallQual','GrLivArea','GarageCars','TotalBsmtSF','FullBath','YearBuilt']

#set my model to DecisionTree
model = DecisionTreeRegressor()

#set prediction data to factors that will predict, and set target to SalePrice
train_data = train[desired_factors]
test_data = test[desired_factors]
target = train.SalePrice

#fitting model with prediction data and telling it my target
model.fit(train_data, target)

model.predict(test_data.head())
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. 
The answer i get is in form of arrays, can I enter than at as new field in the data set? Like a new column and add the array into that?

Comment: You'll want to compare what the model is `predict`ing against `test.SalePrice`.
Assuming you're using http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.predict , i think what you should be getting out is a 1xN (N is length of test set) matrix (i.e., vector) where the `i`th result of `model.predict` corresponds to the `i`th row in your input data corresponds to the `i`th value in your target (`test.SalePrice`).
Not sure how to ideally do that given your data structures.

Comment: I'd do something like 
`actuals = model.predict(test_data) <new line>for target, actual in zip(test.SalePrice, actuals): <new line>    print(target == actual)`
  , but then put some sort of meaninful accumulation of successes and failures inside that loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are already using the trained model for prediction (`model.predict(prdata.head())`). If you want to use that model to predict on other test data, simply supply the other test data instead of `prdata.head()`. For example, you can use the model to predict all samples from `prdata` by removing `.head()` which restricts the DataFrame to the first 5 rows (but you just used this data to train the model; it's just an example).

Keep in mind, you still need a model to make predictions. Typically, you'll train a model and then present it with test data. Changing all of the references of `train` to `test` will not work, because you will not have a model for making predictions based on your test data unless you've saved it from training and restored it prior to presenting it with test data.

In your code, you are actually using your `test.csv` data file to *train* your model as you pass the data to the `model.fit` method. Typically, you will not train your model with data intended for testing.

Comment: Oh yes. I can't believe how stupid I was and was calling model.fit() on my test data. All I did now was do, model.predict(test.head()) and it worked. But what doesn't seem to work is when i use model.predict(test) it gives me an error, but when i used head, it doesn't

Comment: Did you include (only) the same columns before presenting it to your model?

Comment: Yes except the SalePrice which is my target variable

Comment: Please provide more context for help with the error (i.e., post the code/error).